# Leaflet only partly working when LockerService is ON

Tags: locker-service

Leaflet's methods such as `marker.bindPopup('Hello')` is not working when Locker Service is enabled.

Any tip for making it work?

Comment: The issue has been reported. We have not had time to investigate yet. Could I ask you to post some repro steps?

Comment: Hi, started off with this post: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/11/lightning-map-component-revisited.html

Comment: Right... I'll look at it today.

Comment: HI, Is this issue resolved ?